# После сборки проекта maven пропадает папка resources

Tags: java, maven, resources

До сборки проекта путь к ресурсам такой "src/main/resources/", после сборки этот путь уже не работает, т.к в файле jar ресурсы находятся в самом начале. Папок src, main и resources уже нет. Как сделать так, чтобы путь работал и до сборки, и после?

Comment: Если пути нет, то как он может работать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно обращаетесь к ресурсам. Директория `src/main/resources/` является корневой для ресурсных файлов в исходном коде. Обращение к ресурсам должно осуществляться не как обращение к обычным файлам, а при помощи `Class#getResourceAsStream()` относительно classpath. Например если у вас есть `src/main/resources/com/example/myprogram/file.properties` то путь к нему в вашем коде будет `/com/example/myprogram/file.properties`.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо